# decomposition according to embeddings

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

Let $V$ a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ and let $F$ be a number field. Assume that there is an injective morphism of rings $F \hookrightarrow End(V)$. I would like to understand why $V_\mathbb{C}:=V \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{C}$ decomposes into a direct sum

$$
V_\mathbb{C}=\bigoplus_{\sigma \in Hom(F, \mathbb{C})} V_\sigma 
$$

according to complex embeddings of $F$. My idea is the following: if $F=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ then the endomorphism $\alpha \in End(V)$ has the same minimal polynomial as $\alpha$ viewed as an element of $F$. Its roots are $\{\sigma(\alpha)\}_{\sigma \in Hom(F, \mathbb{C})}$ so one can define

$$
V_\sigma=\{ x \in V_\mathbb{C}| \alpha \cdot x=\sigma(\alpha)x\} 
$$

1) Why this is independent of $\alpha$?

2) Is there a more conceptual way to think of it?